# Change visibility of a control by clicking on a button

Tags: c#, visibility

I am working on a project in c#.I have a textbox in my form and a button below it.I want to change the visibility of my textbox by clicking on the button.for example, the textbox is hidden when the form loads.when user clicks on the button the textbox appears on the form.then user clicks on it again for the second time and the textbox hides again.how should i do it.please help me.

Thanks for your kind helps.

Comment: Use a bool and change the bool when the button is clicked, if the bool is true, change the visibility of the button using the button's .Visible property.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = !textBox1.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this should do this

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbProgress.Visible = !tbProgress.Visible;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    bool showtext = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Visible = showtext;
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showtext = !showtext;
        textBox1.Visible = showtext;
    }
```

Comment: You can never unhide the textbox if you are always setting it to true.

Comment: Was typing faster than I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        bool buttonvisible = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Visible = false;
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(buttonvisible)
            {
                buttonvisible = false;
                button1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                buttonvisible = true;
                button1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or simple, but less editable:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = !button1.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Pick it as an answer, when you used my answer:)